# How to group commands together for control operators || and &&?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to be able to group commands together so that if one out of a group of commands fail, another is executed, i.e.

```
$ ping 1; echo 1 || echo 2
```

will return the equivalent of

```
$ ping 1; echo 2
```

with the result

```
connect: Invalid argument
2
```

i.e. the first two commands `ping 1` and `echo 1` should be grouped together such that if one of them fails, the third `echo 2` will be executed.

---

Things I have tried,

- `$ (ping 1; echo 1) || echo 2`
- `$ (( ping 1; echo 1 )) || echo 2`
- `$ [[ ping 1; echo 1 )) || echo 2`
- `$ { ping 1; echo 1; } || echo 2`
- `$ eval "ping 1; echo 1" || echo 2`
- `$ function try_ping { ping 1; echo 1; }; try_ping || echo 2`

---

**EDIT** I still need all commands in this first group to run, so `&&` would not work for me.

1. Run all the commands in group 1
2. If any of the commands in group 1 fail (not exit status of zero)
3. Then run the second group

For example,

```
function my_ping {
    local exit=0
    command1
    exit=$(( exit + $? ))
    command2
    exit=$(( exit + $? ))
    if [[ "$exit" -ne "0" ]]; then
        command3
    fi
}
```

Comment: When you write `ping 1`, do you mean that only as an example? "Invalid argument" is from ping.

Comment: @dbalakirev Yes, it's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
darby@darbycrash:~$ ping 1 2>/dev/null && echo 1 || echo 2
2
darby@darbycrash:~$
```

You can use && for run commands together, if one fail the chain is broken.
This is your example but fixed.
Enjoy.

P.S. I have redirected error message to null.

**Update after your edit**

This script run all commands of the first group and if someone exit without exit code 0 set a variable that using a if run the second group or alert you that you don't need more to run nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash

function check () {
    $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
    echo $?
}

command=("curl -sSL google.com" "echo 1" 'ping localhost -c 1' 'ls' 'false')

for ((i=0;i<${#command[@]};i++)); do
    echo "Command \"${command[$i]}\" returned value $(check "${command[$i]}")"
    if (($(check "${command[$i]}") != 0)); then second=1; fi
done

if ((second == 1)); then
    echo "I must run second group of commands because something have not worked!"
    echo 2
else
    echo "All is gone without issues! Goodbye $USER!"
    exit 0
fi
```

**Output**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash ex
Command "curl -sSL google.com" returned value 0
Command "echo 1" returned value 0
Command "ping localhost -c 1" returned value 0
Command "ls" returned value 0
Command "false" returned value 1
I must run second group of commands because something have not worked!
2
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash ex
Command "curl -sSL google.com" returned value 0
Command "echo 1" returned value 0
Command "ping localhost -c 1" returned value 0
Command "ls" returned value 0
Command "true" returned value 0 # I have changed false to true in the command array
All is gone without issues! Goodbye darby!
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```

Comment: I need the second command to run, even if the first fails. Sorry for the ambiguous phrasing, I've updated to clarify my answer.

Comment: I have updated my code. I hope that this can help you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
OK=1
ping 1 || OK=0
echo 1 || OK=0
[[ "$OK" == "0" ]] && echo 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
ls && tree && echo success || echo epic fail
```

If commands `ls` or `tree` would fail, 'epic fail' would be printed.

Comment: I need the second command to run, even if the first fails. Sorry for the ambiguous phrasing, I've updated to clarify my answer.